# Mountain Lion - Cycle though windows not working on Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Since updating to Mountain Lion, the keyboard shortcut for cycling through windows is not working for me in Terminal (and is driving me nuts!).

Is there any known fix for this issue? The keyboard shortcut shows up on the Window menu as expected, but doesn't work.

I am, of couse, pressing CMD-`, and is not cycling. Selecting the option from the Window menu does cycle through the windows, though.

**Update:** Although not resolved in Mountain Lion, this got fixed in Mavericks. It was weird: it works properly on Lion and Mavericks, but breaks on Mountain Lion.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The only thing I noticed is that I've got 2 keyboard layouts on my computer (english and international-english) this problem occurs for me only when I'm using the international-english kbd layout.... Is it the same with you?

Comment: BTW When I'm on intl-eng layout the cycling shortcut is mapped on cmd+"["...

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab of the `Keyboard` System Preference-- make sure that `Move focus to next window` is set to your liking (in the `Keyboard & Text` item) and that there are no conflicts with any other shortcut settings.  Barring that, a complete re-install of ML has fixed other quirks that cropped up when I upgraded.

Comment: The shortcut is properly set. It turns out to be a bug with the US International keyboard. Changing to US fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using MoLion for months and have never experienced this issue (and I would have). I tested this again just now with several terminal windows open, and no issue.

You are pressing cmd - ` , right?

Comment: Of course I am :)

Comment: Then you've got me :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting 'cycle through windows' confused with 'cycle through tabs'?

Cycle Through Windows shortcut is CMD-` where Cycle Through Tabs is CMD-}

Comment: No. As I stated, I'm doing CMD-`. It was fixed in Mavericks.