# Keyboard sequence command + [ in `terminal`

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut, shortcut-menu

When I press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> in the Terminal app on my 10.15.7 MBP machine, it causes the Terminal to rotate between the open Terminal windows. The sequence  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> cycles in the opposite direction. However, the **Window** menu lists only the sequence <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> for cycling through windows. Under **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** and **System Preferences** > **App Shortcuts**, I have ensured that I don't have any additional shortcuts listed that would cause this behavior. So my questions are:

1. Is this the standard behavior for the Terminal app, or have I somehow added this behavior for me personally?
2. If standard, is this configurable somewhere so that I could disable this behavior if I like?
3. Why is this keyboard shortcut behavior not listed in the menu bar like the other shortcuts I see there?

I saw another user mention a [related bug on Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/78933/141659), and I am using a non-standard keyboard layout, but

1. the issue they describe was related to the us-intl keyboard layout and
2. their issue was purportedly fixed in Mavericks.

Let me note that I do not see this same behavior with iTerm2, so the current somewhat-drastic workaround is to use iTerm2 instead of the built-in Terminal.

Comment: Cmd [ & ] are global shortcuts for Back & Forward (in history). Terminal doesn't have those commands, so they can't be changed in Keyboard prefs. Both just beep as 'not found' when I test them here. Cycle through Tabs is Cmd/Shift/[ & ] which sends { & } on a UK English keyboard.

Comment: @Tetsujin, do you mean they are shortcuts in your web browser? I do see that `⌘+⇧+]` and `⌘+⇧+[` tab behavior in Chrome. Different than you, I'm on a US keyboard using a dvorak layout. But 1. My problem occurs specifically in terminal. 2. My `terminal` switches windows on `⌘+]` and `⌘+[` (note: no `⇧`). I don't have any global "move focus" shortcuts in my `System Preferences > Keyboard` menu; I disabled shortcuts for all those behaviors. So I don't think this really explains the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: By global, I mean they tend to be used anywhere the behaviour is appropriate. Browser, Finder etc use Cmd/[ & ] for history, Cmd/Shift/[ & ] for tabs. As they appear in menus in these apps, they could be added/changed in Prefs. Any that don't have a menu item, of course, cannot.

Comment: But @Tetsujin, you say these sequences behave differently for you in the `terminal` app than they behave for me in mine? That is, when you try those same sequences, you get the bell, which beeps as not found? Is that correct? If so, what version of MacOS are you running, and what keyboard layout?

Comment: I'm running Mojave, on a UK English keyboard [as already mentioned].